# Finding the average time between an array of timestamps in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get the average time between these timestamps. But it keeps coming out as

```
"average = ", "Wed Dec 31 1969 20:48:03 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

How can I get the correct average between the dates below ?

Adding up the sum of all the dates is not going to give me the average between the first date and the last date.

Here is my code below.

```js
const timeStamps = [
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Mon Aug 01 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:42 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:02 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:55 GMT-0700 (PST)",
];

const sortedDates = timeStamps.map((t) => new Date(t)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
const average =
  (sortedDates[sortedDates.length - 1] - sortedDates[0]) / sortedDates.length -
  1;
  
console.log("average = ", new Date(average).toString());
```

Comment: Your calculation will produce a number representing the difference in ms between the earliest and latest date. You're then dividing that by 5 and subtracting 1. This will not produce a timestamp suitable for use in the `Date` constructor

Comment: An average is the sum of values divided by the count. This is not what you're doing. Are you looking for the _median_ value? Even then, I don't think you're going about it the right way

Comment: It might help if you illustrated what the expected answer is and why, in plain terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const timeStamps = ['Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)', 'Mon Aug 01 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)', 'Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:42 GMT-0700 (PST)',  'Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:02 GMT-0700 (PST)', 'Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:55 GMT-0700 (PST)' ]

const ts = timeStamps.map(time => new Date(time).getTime());


const sortedDates = ts.sort((a, b) => a - b);
const average =
  (sortedDates[sortedDates.length - 1] + sortedDates[0]) / 2;

console.log("average = ", new Date(average));
```

Comment: I'm not looking ro the average of all of them. I'm looking for the average between them.

Comment: in that case let me update my answer!

Comment: @me-me i think average = total / count, so just add the first and last dates and divide them by two.

Comment: Why add the first and last ? I thought it would be to find the difference by subtraction ?

Comment: I won't pretend to be a mathematician, but subtracting them will give you the difference in milliseconds. eg. avg of 1 and 5 => (5 + 1) / 2 = 3 make more sense than (5 - 1) / 2  = 2. But hey you can google it for a better information.

Comment: @me-me because `((b - a) / 2) + a` is the same as `(a + b) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic mean or the average is the sum of all the numbers divided by the count of numbers in any collection.

We could sum up all the timestamps and divide it with the array length.

Note that the items in the `timestamps` array are strings, we could get their [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with `new Date(timestamp).valueOf()`.

```js
const timestamps = [
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Mon Aug 01 2022 09:47:39 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:42 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:02 GMT-0700 (PST)",
  "Tue Aug 02 2022 09:47:55 GMT-0700 (PST)",
];

let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
    sum += new Date(timestamps[i]).valueOf();
}

const average = sum / timestamps.length;
console.log(average); // or console.log(new Date(average));
```

Comment: This will give me the average of all of them. I'm looking for the average between the first and last date.